# ¿Cómo almacenar pdfs en una base de datos en sqlServer con visual basic?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

es que yo eh querido crear una aplicación en visual basic.net de una base de datos de SQL server, pero eh querido saber como almacenar archivos de pdf en sql server, si los tengo en una carpeta en mi pc  como agregar la ruta de donde los tengo guardados, no sé si es en sql server o es en visual basic en el datagridview, es una aplicación donde pueda guardar y ver informes de clientes o sobre los datos de la base de datos.

Comment: Pero que es lo que quieres guardar el fichero o la ruta en donde está el fichero

Comment: @Japv guardar ruta del fichero por medio de un hipervínculo con link label